# nginx Permission Denied

Tags: nginx, centos

I'm trying to set up nginx. When serving a file I get the following error:

`[crit] 64347#0: *4 stat() "/home/zmbq/web/static/index.html" failed (13: Permission denied)`

I've set the proper permissions to the file and all its parent directories, restart nginx and the error persists.

Running `sudo -u nginx cat /home/zmbq/web/static/index.html` displays the file's content. `stat`ing the same file also works.

Permissions down the path:

```
[zmbq@csm-web var]$ ll /
drwxr-xr-x.   3 root root   18 Aug 30 09:25 home

[zmbq@csm-web var]$ ll /home
drwxr-xr-x. 13 zmbq zmbq 4096 Aug 30 12:17 zmbq

[zmbq@csm-web var]$ ll /home/zmbq
drwxrwxr-x.  8 zmbq zmbq       77 Aug 30 11:53 web

[zmbq@csm-web var]$ ll /home/zmbq/web
drwxrwxr-x. 4 zmbq nginx 4096 Aug 30 11:46 static

[zmbq@csm-web var]$ ll /home/zmbq/web/static
-rw-rw-r--. 1 zmbq nginx     683 Aug 30 11:46 index.html
```

Comment: Please show us the permissions you have set. Also: Check SELinux on CentOS.

Comment: SELinux seems to be enabled, I need to figure out how to see how it applies to the nginx process (the nginx user can access the file). I've added the directory structure with the relevant permissions.

Comment: It is SELinux. If I disable it it works, however, none of the tips here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22586166/871910 seem to work.When it's enabled, I can't access the files.
Perhaps I should just copy everything to /usr/share/nginx/html and not worry about it.

Comment: You should not put any files in `/usr/share/nginx/html`. That directory is for the nginx default error pages, and is owned by the system package. It may change or disappear unexpectedly. Use a standard directory such as `/srv/www` or a subdirectory thereof. For your answer, see the linked duplicate.